# Python server is killed when started using docker-compose exec

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker-compose

I start docker container and want to start simple python server in it.
I can't use `ENTRYPOINT/CMD` of Dockerfile as it is already used for other things.

I am trying to do it the following way:

```
docker-compose exec <service_name> /bin/bash -c "./server.py &"
```

But as soon as `docker-compose exec` ends server stops.

Yet if I run application written on C++ in the same way it continues to run:

```
docker-compose exec <service_name> /bin/bash -c "./app &"
```

I inspected this using `htop` and found out that both `server.py` and `app` start as child processes but after end of `docker-compose exec` `app` reattaches and `server.py` stops.

1. How can I make my python server continue to run starting it through `docke-compose exec?

Comment: Can you try `/bin/bash -c "nohup ./server.py &"` ?

Comment: Could also try `--detach` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `nohup` like `/bin/bash -c "nohup ./server.py &` as proposed in commentaries did help.